# Not able to calculate total hours

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. We have a code to add total hours based on "employee id". Below code showing correct result for "excessTime". But for "totalHours" it is showing "NaN". Does anyone know why it is showing "NaN" while adding "totalHours" and How to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var input = [
    {
        "employeeId": "101",
        "totalHours": "1:46",
        "excessTime": "2:15"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "102",
        "totalHours": "1:15",
        "excessTime": "1:30"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "101",
        "totalHours": "1:15",
        "excessTime": "3:00"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "102",
        "totalHours": "1:00",
        "excessTime": "2:15"
    }
]

    var obj = input.reduce( function(init, e){
    if (init[e["employeeId"]] == undefined){
         init[e["employeeId"]] = {hours: parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[0]),minutes: parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1])};
         init[e["employeeId"]].timeString = e["totalHours"];
         init[e["employeeId"]] = {hrs: parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[0]),mns: parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[1])};
         init[e["employeeId"]].excessString = e["excessTime"];
         return init;
      } else {
         init[e["employeeId"]].hours += (parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[0]) + Math.floor((init[e["employeeId"]].minutes + parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1]))/60));
         init[e["employeeId"]].minutes = (init[e["employeeId"]].minutes + parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1]))%60;
         init[e["employeeId"]].timeString = init[e["employeeId"]].minutes > 9 ? init[e["employeeId"]].hours + ":" + init[e["employeeId"]].minutes : init[e["employeeId"]].hours + ":0" + init[e["employeeId"]].minutes;

         init[e["employeeId"]].hrs += (parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[0]) + Math.floor((init[e["employeeId"]].mns + parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[1]))/60));
         init[e["employeeId"]].mns = (init[e["employeeId"]].mns + parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[1]))%60;
         init[e["employeeId"]].excessString = init[e["employeeId"]].mns > 9 ? init[e["employeeId"]].hrs + ":" + init[e["employeeId"]].mns : init[e["employeeId"]].hrs + ":0" + init[e["employeeId"]].mns;
         return init;
      }
  }, {});

var arr = [];
for (var prop in obj) arr.push({employeeId: prop, totalHours: obj[prop].timeString, excessTime: obj[prop].excessString});
console.log(arr);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "employeeId": "101",
        "totalHours": "NaN:0NaN",
        "excessTime": "5:15"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "102",
        "totalHours": "NaN:0NaN",
        "excessTime": "3:45"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to assign values to the `hours` and `minutes` properties, but they are `undefined`. You need to assign them to their hours and minutes respectively in your first `if` statement:

```
init[e["employeeId"]].hours = parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[0]);
init[e["employeeId"]].minutes = parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1]);
```

All together looks like this:

```
var input = [
    {
        "employeeId": "101",
        "totalHours": "1:46",
        "excessTime": "2:15"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "102",
        "totalHours": "1:15",
        "excessTime": "1:30"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "101",
        "totalHours": "1:15",
        "excessTime": "3:00"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "102",
        "totalHours": "1:00",
        "excessTime": "2:15"
    }
]

    var obj = input.reduce( function(init, e){
    if (init[e["employeeId"]] == undefined){
         init[e["employeeId"]] = {hours: parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[0]),minutes: parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1])};
         init[e["employeeId"]].timeString = e["totalHours"];
         init[e["employeeId"]] = {hrs: parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[0]),mns: parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[1])};
         init[e["employeeId"]].excessString = e["excessTime"];
         init[e["employeeId"]].hours = parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[0]);
         init[e["employeeId"]].minutes = parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1]);
         return init;
      } else {
         init[e["employeeId"]].hours += (parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[0]) + Math.floor((init[e["employeeId"]].minutes + parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1]))/60));
         init[e["employeeId"]].minutes = (init[e["employeeId"]].minutes + parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1]))%60;
         init[e["employeeId"]].timeString = init[e["employeeId"]].minutes > 9 ? init[e["employeeId"]].hours + ":" + init[e["employeeId"]].minutes : init[e["employeeId"]].hours + ":0" + init[e["employeeId"]].minutes;

         init[e["employeeId"]].hrs += (parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[0]) + Math.floor((init[e["employeeId"]].mns + parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[1]))/60));
         init[e["employeeId"]].mns = (init[e["employeeId"]].mns + parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[1]))%60;
         init[e["employeeId"]].excessString = init[e["employeeId"]].mns > 9 ? init[e["employeeId"]].hrs + ":" + init[e["employeeId"]].mns : init[e["employeeId"]].hrs + ":0" + init[e["employeeId"]].mns;
         return init;
      }
  }, {});

var arr = [];
for (var prop in obj) arr.push({employeeId: prop, totalHours: obj[prop].timeString, excessTime: obj[prop].excessString});
console.log(arr);
```

**Result:**

```
  [{
        "employeeId": "101",
        "totalHours": "3:01",
        "excessTime": "5:15"
    }, {
        "employeeId": "102",
        "totalHours": "2:15",
        "excessTime": "3:45"
    }]
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/v7eckcny/

Comment: I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'hours' of undefined(…)

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your reduce `if` clause your are initializing `init[e["employeeId"]]` two times 
, so when you initializing it second time your `{hours , minutes}` object getting replaced with `{hrs,mns}` and thats why you are getting NAN in total hour.

you need to initialize it once

```
init[e["employeeId"]] = {hours: parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[0]),minutes: parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1]),hrs: parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[0]),mns: parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[1])};
```

Have a look on below working code snippet.

```js
var input = [
    {
        "employeeId": "101",
        "totalHours": "1:46",
        "excessTime": "2:15"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "102",
        "totalHours": "1:15",
        "excessTime": "1:30"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "101",
        "totalHours": "1:15",
        "excessTime": "3:00"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": "102",
        "totalHours": "1:00",
        "excessTime": "2:15"
    }
];

var obj = input.reduce( function(init, e){
    if (init[e["employeeId"]] == undefined){
      // here you need to change your code like below
         init[e["employeeId"]] = {hours: parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[0]),minutes: parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1]),hrs: parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[0]),mns: parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[1])};
         init[e["employeeId"]].timeString = e["totalHours"];
         init[e["employeeId"]].excessString = e["excessTime"];
         return init;
      } else {
         init[e["employeeId"]].hours += (parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[0]) + Math.floor((init[e["employeeId"]].minutes + parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1]))/60));
         init[e["employeeId"]].minutes = (init[e["employeeId"]].minutes + parseInt(e["totalHours"].split(":")[1]))%60;
         init[e["employeeId"]].timeString = init[e["employeeId"]].minutes > 9 ? init[e["employeeId"]].hours + ":" + init[e["employeeId"]].minutes : init[e["employeeId"]].hours + ":0" + init[e["employeeId"]].minutes;

         init[e["employeeId"]].hrs += (parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[0]) + Math.floor((init[e["employeeId"]].mns + parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[1]))/60));
         init[e["employeeId"]].mns = (init[e["employeeId"]].mns + parseInt(e["excessTime"].split(":")[1]))%60;
         init[e["employeeId"]].excessString = init[e["employeeId"]].mns > 9 ? init[e["employeeId"]].hrs + ":" + init[e["employeeId"]].mns : init[e["employeeId"]].hrs + ":0" + init[e["employeeId"]].mns;
      
         return init;
      }
  }, {});

var arr = [];
for (var prop in obj) arr.push({employeeId: prop, totalHours: obj[prop].timeString, excessTime: obj[prop].excessString});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because of being String , use parseInt() to convert string to integer
like this example :

```
var a = parseInt("10");
```